# How to properly invalidate JWT tokens and sessions in this use case?

Tags: authentication, authorization, jwt, node.js, angularjs

I am building a web app, which is made of a Node.js Backend and Angular (**NOT** AngularJS!!! I only used the tag, because Angular was not available..) Frontend.

How do I properly secure this app? I already have an idea to use JWT tokens (I already implemented this) with a set expiration date, which will be way longer than the Frontend timer. The frontend timer should be like 15 minutes of inactivity. But how do I secure this Frontend timer against RAM modification with tools like Cheat Engine and also JavaScript modification/injection/editing? Are there any flaws in this logic? Any suggestions?

I was thinking of renewing JWT tokens, but that's apparently not possible. I am sure there's something wrong with my logic but I can't put my finger on it. Maybe I am lacking general sessions and their management?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## You can't rely on the client code

General rule of thumb: once you send code down to the client to run on the user's machine, *[it's not your code anymore](https://www.marshall.edu/it/departments/information-security/10-immutable-laws-of-security/)*. The only security you can count on is security that's enforced by the server.

## Stateful vs stateless

When designing a JWT mechanism you have to choose whether you want the server to track sessions in some sort of cache or not

Pros of stateless:

- JWT is entirely self-contained; everything the server needs to know about the user and session is contained in the JWT (either a signed JWS if the contents are non-sensitive, or an encrypted JWE if the contents are sensitive).
- Low server memory footprint (no cache) and latency (no db lookups).
- High horizontal scalability because there is no cache to syncronize.

Cons of stateless:

- No way to revoke a token -- the JWT *will* be valid until it expires (for example, no way to robustly do a logout mechanism).

## Hybrid solution: short-lived JWT with Refresh token

The best-of-both-worlds solution that I like is to issue sort-lived stateless JWTs (expires in 5 - 15 mins), and also issue a long-lived stateful Refresh token (expires in weeks - months). That way the flood of API requests that happen on page load are using the high-performance stateless token, but you get to enforce logout every 5 - 15 mins when the client needs to trade in its Refresh token for a fresh JWT and Refresh token.

Auth0 has a nice writeup of this solution here:

- https://auth0.com/blog/refresh-tokens-what-are-they-and-when-to-use-them/